# ERRO TO MANY REDIRECTS Spring Security Core e Grails

Tags: groovy, spring-security, grails

Bom dia, estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação Grails e resolvi implementar autorização e autenticação o mesmo está funcionando perfeitamente no entanto resolvi mudar o formulário de login para o meu formulário e não o padrão do Spring Security Core no entanto estou tendo o seguinte erro ao tentar acessar a URL no Google Chrome, **"ERRO_TO_MANY_REDIRECTS"**, as linha que eu alterei no meu Config.groovy foi:

```
 // Added by the Spring Security Core plugin:
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'org.lab2.security.User'
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'org.lab2.security.UserRole'
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'org.lab2.security.Role'

// Aqui entra as alterações feitas por mim

   grails.plugin.springsecurity.auth.loginFormUrl = '/areaRestrita/login'  //Mostra qual a tela de login
    rails.plugin.springsecurity.auth.afterLogoutUrl = '/areaRestrita/logout' //Mostra qual a tela de logout
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl = '/contato/index' //Mostra qual URL chamada caso o login funcione

// Aqui termina minhas alterações

    grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
        '/':                              ['permitAll'],
        '/index':                         ['permitAll'],
        '/index.gsp':                     ['permitAll'],
        '/assets/**':                     ['permitAll'],
        '/**/js/**':                      ['permitAll'],
        '/**/css/**':                     ['permitAll'],
        '/**/images/**':                  ['permitAll'],
        '/**/favicon.ico':                ['permitAll']
    ]
```

Sendo que as linha em negrito foram as adicionadas por mim para determinar o form de login e logout, juntamente com a pagina inicial ao logar. Caso alguém tenha uma solução ficarei grato pela ajuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gustavo, o que está ocorrendo é que a sua página de login é a `'/areaRestrita/login'`, e para acessar esta área é necessário estar logado no sistema.
O que acontece? Ao acessar a área de login, por esta ser uma área restrita, o usuário é redirecionado para a página de Login.

Como não tem permissão, vai para a página de login, e assim continua de forma indefinida, até que a exceção é lançada.
Recomendo que indique que a página de login não é restrita, seu código ficará assim:

```
 // Added by the Spring Security Core plugin:
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'org.lab2.security.User'
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'org.lab2.security.UserRole'
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'org.lab2.security.Role'

// Aqui entra as alterações feitas por mim

   grails.plugin.springsecurity.auth.loginFormUrl = '/areaRestrita/login'  //Mostra qual a tela de login
    rails.plugin.springsecurity.auth.afterLogoutUrl = '/areaRestrita/logout' //Mostra qual a tela de logout
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl = '/contato/index' //Mostra qual URL chamada caso o login funcione

// Aqui termina minhas alterações

    grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
        '/areaRestrita/login':            ['permitAll'], //Alteração para deixar a tela de login acessível a usuários anônimos.
        '/':                              ['permitAll'],
        '/index':                         ['permitAll'],
        '/index.gsp':                     ['permitAll'],
        '/assets/**':                     ['permitAll'],
        '/**/js/**':                      ['permitAll'],
        '/**/css/**':                     ['permitAll'],
        '/**/images/**':                  ['permitAll'],
        '/**/favicon.ico':                ['permitAll']
    ]
```

PS: Não tenho nada de ambiente do rails ou grails instalado aqui, pra falar a verdade nunca usei o grails, mas imagino que o problema seja esse.
Minha fonte de pesquisa foi um erro similar ao seu: http://www.grailsbrasil.com/post/show/1568

Comment: Perfeito cara, funcionou a pagina dr login foi exibida no entanto não esta logando.

Comment: Sugiro marcar esta resposta como correta então e criar uma nova pergunta referente a página de login, exibindo o código fonte dela e detalhando melhor o problema.

Comment: Alterando o formulário de login do Spring Security Core e Groovy Grails - http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/63755/22504

Comment: Dê uma olhada nesse caso talvez possa me ajudar

Comment: Eu vi o problema que você postou referente a view, porém, como ainda não tenho reputação no pt.stackoverflow não posso fazer comentários lá. Você pode postar também o código do controle que está recebendo a requisição?

Comment: Não postei o código do controller aqui devido ao fato dessa controller ser gerado pelo scaffolding do grails de forma dinâmica isso fica como responsabilidade do Spring Security Core, no entanto ja encontrei a solução era erro do Tomcat. Qualquer coisa da uma olhada la no comentário da questão.