# Alterando o formulário de login do Spring Security Core e Groovy Grails

Tags: spring, groovy, grails

Boa tarde, fiz uma alteração na minha aplicação para utilizar o meu form de login ao invés do padrão do Spring Security Core, o redirecionamento está ocorrendo normalmente, no entanto quando cliclk no botão para Entrar nada ocorre. Segue abaixo o código do meu formulário:

```
<from action='${request.contextPath}/j_spring_security_check' method="POST" name="logar" id="logar" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="username">Email</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text"  placeholder="Email" name="j_username" id="username">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="password">Senha</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="password"  placeholder="Senha" name="j_password" id="password">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <label class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox"> Lembre-se de mim
                </label>
                <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Entrar" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </from>
```

Alguma sugestão ?

Comment: Pessoal eu mesmo encontrei a solução, o grails permite que editemos a aplicação com a mesma em execução no entanto parece que isso não funciona muito bem com o plugin do spring security core eu simplesmente parei a aplicação e iniciei novamente funcionou perfeitamente.